# multidimensional array fetching fail

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one array named `$grouped_types`. When I print it it displays like this:

```
Array
(
[XMU_1_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [port] => 1
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [port] => 2
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [port] => 3
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [port] => 4
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [port] => 5
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [port] => 6
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [port] => 7
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [port] => 8
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [port] => 9
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [port] => 10
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [port] => 11
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [port] => 12
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [port] => 13
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [port] => 14
                [band] => 700
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [port] => 15
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [port] => 16
                [band] => 
                [name] => XMU_1_1
            )
    )

[DUS_1_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [port] => A
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [port] => B
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [port] => C
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [port] => D
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_1
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [port] => E
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_1
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [port] => F
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_1
            )
    )

[DUS_1_2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [port] => A
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [port] => B
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [port] => C
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_2
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [port] => D
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_2
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [port] => E
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_2
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [port] => F
                [band] => 
                [name] => DUS_1_2
            )
    )
)
```

Now I want this array to display like this in a table:

```
XMU_1_1 port    XMU_1_1 band

1               
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14                 700
15
16
```

This is for only one name I want it for every different name. Every name should have different table. How to fetch my array so I can display it for different table? I tried but i don't know how to fetch this type of array.

Comment: _" i tried but"_ - please show what you've tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to cycle through an array is with the `foreach()` loop.With a multi-dimensional array, you'd have to have a one or two nested `foreach()` loops as demonstrated in the code snippet.I'm not saying that's exactly the code that will work for you; it's just to illustrate what nested foreach() loops would look like.Hope it can help you to solve your problem

[LIVE DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wars-5eun)

```
<?php 

echo "<table>";
foreach ($grouped_types as $k => $val) {
    echo "<tr>
            <th>$k port </th>
            <th>$k band </th>
          </tr>";
    if (is_array($val)) {
        foreach ($val as $v) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>" . $v['port'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $v['band'] . "</td>
                  </tr>";
        }
    }

}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Array, this will do as asked using a `foreach()` loop.

```
$array = [

"XMU_1_1" =>[

            [

            "port" => 1,
            "band" => null,
            "name" => "XMU_1_1",

            ],
            [

            "port" => 2,
            "band" => null,
            "name" => "XMU_1_1",

            ],
            [

            "port" => 3,
            "band" => null,
            "name" => "XMU_1_1",

            ],
            [

            "port" => 4,
            "band" => 700,
            "name" => "XMU_1_1",

            ],    
    ]  
];


echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>XMU_1_1 port</th><th>XMU_1_1 band</th></tr>";   

foreach($array['XMU_1_1'] as $v) {

    echo "<tr><td>" . $v['port'] . "</td><td>" . $v['band'] . "</td></tr>"; 

} 

echo "</table>";
```

**Output**

```
XMU_1_1 port    XMU_1_1 band
1   
2   
3   
4   700
```